# Spring security - Algumas dúvidas

Tags: spring, spring-security

Estou implementado o spring security, na aplicação. Está logando corretamente, logout também. Nas páginas abaixo só entra se tiver logado com o role **ROLE_ADMINISTRADOR**.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                // Configuração para todos usuarios do sistema
                .antMatchers("/error/**", "/resources/**", "/jsCss/**", "/webjars/**", "/recuperarSenha").permitAll()
                // Configuração para todos usuarios com permissão de
                // ROLE_ADMINISTRADOR
                .antMatchers("/codigo/**", "/subCodigo/**", "/tipoCredito/**", "/tipoCancelamento/**", "/usuario/**",
                        "/servico/**", "/notaFiscal/**", "/erroAlerta/**", "/credito/**", "/configuracao/**",
                        "/cnaeSubCodigo/**", "/cnae/**", "/erroAlerta/**", "/atualizacaoMonetariaItem/**",
                        "/atualizacaoMonetaria/**", "/dashboardAdmin/**", "/porcentagemReter/**")
                .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRADOR')")
                // Configuração para todos usuarios do sistema
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(loginSucessHandler).permitAll().and().rememberMe()
                // Logout
                .and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).and().sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true).expiredUrl("/login")
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());

    }
```

Estou algumas dúvidas.

1. está parte **.and().sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true).expiredUrl("/login").sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());**, define que um usuário por vez esteja logado, o que está funcionando. Mas o problema é que depois de fazer o logout, não consigo entrar com o mesmo login, ai tenho que parar o servidor, para conseguir logar novamente.

2.Configuração de tempo de sessão, não consegui fazer. Tipo se o usuário não trabalhar com o sistema, ele desloga automaticamente.

3.Não estou conseguindo trabalhar com **CSRF Attacks**, mesmo tirando esta parte do código **http.csrf().disable();**.

Sobre o item 3, estou colocando nas páginas html, mas dá erro

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
    <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Entendo que os seus problemas são relacionados a spring-security, mas acredito que a melhor forma, para você e quem responde, é fazê-las de forma separada, uma vez que suas dúvidas não possuem pré-requisito/ligação/dependência direta para esclarecimento.

Respondendo a sua dúvida 2:

Você pode configurar para todas as sessões colocando no seu web.xml:

```
<session-config>
<session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Ou por sessão, usando:

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60*60);
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas não entendi.

Sobre a segunda, isto é, sobre o tempo, criei esta classe, mas não funciona.

Comment: import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

public class NotaFiscalEletronicaAppHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

 @ Override
 public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
  event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(60);
 }

 @ Override
 public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
  // session destroyed
 }
}

Comment: Tentou a primeira opção ?